# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un carousel que muestre 1, 2 y 3 imagenes dependiendo la resolucion de pantalla?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

bueno mi problema consta en que necesito hacer un carousel que dependiendo la resolución muestre cierta cantidad de imágenes, por ejemplo:
resolución móvil  1 imagen de todo el espacio disponible.
resolución mediana  2 imágenes que se dividan la mitad del espacio disponible.
resolución larga  3 imágenes que se dividan el total de espacio disponible.

encontré un ejemplo en
[CODEPLY](https://www.codeply.com/go/KlL4X3ZYEo/bootstrap-4-responsive-carousel-one-at-a-time)

pero este solo esta adaptado para 3 imagenes en las resoluciones mediana y larga

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: @phpMyGuel es bueno el ejemplo pero sería mucho mejor si no tuviera que implementar ninguna librería extra, agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?